# How do I get content from a table using its ID with a regex?

Tags: regex, html-table, html-content-extraction

I need to sort a html string so I get the content I need. Now I need to loop through the table rows in a table that have an ID. How do I do this with a regex?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions cannot be used to parse HTML; HTML is not regular. Use a proper HTML parser library.

Comment: u got any suggestions for this? i use asp.net c#

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how regular the HTML text is.  For example, given this table:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>Apple</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>Ball</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>Cookie</td></tr>
<table>
```

The following regex expression finds the IDs in the first column:

```
(?<=<tr><td>).*?(?=</td>)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the page through an html-parser like BeautifulSoup, then you can prettify it so that this kind of regex has a chance.  But if you are parsing the html anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim HTML As String = contentText
Dim options As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("<table[^>]*>(.*)</table>", options)
Dim match As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(HTML)
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
For Each items As Match In match
    sb.Append(items.ToString & vbLf)
Next
TextBox.Text = sb.ToString
```